# How can I count the number of leaves of a node in an extjs tree?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, nodes, cascade

I have a tree made in extjs 4.x, and I need to count for any node, the number of leaves of that node.
And I mean the total number of leaves, which means also the leaves of the "sub-nodes" of that node.
I saw there is a cascade method, but I can't manage to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var leafCount = 0;
treePanel.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function(node){
    if(node.isLeaf()) leafCount++;
});
```